# Is there a way to get the current controller instance in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to do this using DI? I tried `IScopedInstance<Controller>` but this gives me null. Poked around aspnet's source code but didn't win. Any ideas?

I have a controller that accepts different `IPaymentMethod`s. The `IPaymentMethod` *can* be a `ViewComponent` that *can* render Views. If the `IPaymentMethod` is a `ViewComponent`, I want it to use MVC's built-in model binding on post back.

```
public class XController : Controller
{

    // ctor, props, ...

    public IActionResult Checkout()
    {
        return View(new Model
        {
            PaymentMethodId = 1,
            PaymentMethodType = typeof(MyPaymentMethod) // The razor file will use this type to render it as a ViewComponent
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Checkout(Model model)
    {
        var paymentMethod = _paymentService.GetPaymentMethodById(model.PaymentMethodId);

        paymentMethod.ProcessPayment();

        // ..
    }
}
```

This is where I need the controller to be injected. I wanted to make use of the built-in MVC validation and model binding.

```
public class MyPaymentMethod : IPaymentMethod
{
    private Controller _currentController;

    public MyPaymentMethod(IScopedInstance<Controller> controller)
    {
        _currentController = controller.Value;
    }

    public void ProcessPayment()
    {
        var model = new PaymentModel();

        _currentController.TryUpdateModel(model, typeof(PaymentModel), null);

        if (!_currentController.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return; // or exception
        }

        // Process Payment using model
    }

    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        // returns View
    }
}

public interface IPaymentMethod
{
    void ProcessPayment();
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. From what scope or context are you trying to get the current controller?

Comment: Note that the whole point of loose-coupling and separation-of-concerns is that other layers in your application should be completely ignorant of the current controller.

Comment: @Dai True. This is an exception though because the class sits in the 'web' layer.

Comment: _"The IPaymentMethod can be a ViewComponent that can render Views."_ - why is that a good idea?

Comment: I'm not in anyway saying it's _good_ but it has to be in our case.

Answer (score 0):

**This no longer works with beta7**

At this time of writing (`beta6`), this probably isn't supported and there is a good reason for it: Controllers in ASP.NET 5 does not need to inherit from the `Controller` class. I have, however, found a way for this to work using `ActionFilters`.

```
public class ScopeControllerActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IScopedInstance<Controller> _controller;

    public ScopeControllerActionFilterAttribute(IScopedInstance<Controller> controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (_controller.Value == null)
        {
            _controller.Value = context.Controller as Controller;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that depending on the stage of the http request lifecycle, the `Value` of `IScopedInstance<Controller>` may still be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Since the model instance is required in the `ProcessPayment` method, why not simply pass it as a parameter?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Checkout(PaymentModel model)
{
    var paymentMethod = _paymentService.GetPaymentMethodById(model.PaymentMethodId);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return; // or exception
    }

    paymentMethod.ProcessPayment(model);

    // ..
}

public void ProcessPayment(PaymentModel model)
{
    // Process Payment using model
}
```

Your service is taking on responsibilities that belong to the controller - namely checking `ModelState.IsValid`.

```
public interface IPaymentMethod
{
    void ProcessPayment(PaymentModel model);
}
```

You may wish to also pass just the properties that are needed from the payment model, or you may wish to make an `IPaymentModel` interface to decouple your model from your `PaymentService`. In that case, your `IPaymentModel` would go into a shared layer.

```
public interface IPaymentMethod
{
    void ProcessPayment(IPaymentModel model);
}
```

Comment: This was actually the first option but was quickly ditched because of how the layers are implemented. In the real project, there is an IPaymentService that can accept any IPaymentMethod. The IPaymentService will call the ProcessPayment method of the passed IPaymentMethod. The IPaymentService cannot have any reference to any _HTTP_ component. I simply left this part out in my example for the sake of simplicity.